# Why imagettftext does not work?

Tags: php, image, imagettftext

I have problems with the "imagettftext" function. The following code works if I comment the problematic line (I see a yellow rectangle).

```
session_start();
$text = $_SESSION['code'];
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$image = imagecreate(150, 15);
$red_bg = 255; $green_bg = 255; $blue_bg = 155;
$bg_col = imagecolorallocate($image, $red_bg, $green_bg, $blue_bg);
$red_txt = 0; $green_txt = 0; $blue_txt = 0;
$text_col = imagecolorallocate($image, $red_txt, $green_txt, $blue_txt);
$font = "LucidaSansRegular.ttf";
$link_col = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
//imagettftext($image, 10.0, 0.0, 5, 5, $text_col, $font, "aaaaa");
imagegif($image);
```

But if I uncomment the problematic line (to show some text) I get a problem. Mozilla writes me "The image cannot be displayed, because it contains errors".

May be this is related with the access to my font file (LucidaSansRegular.ttf). All files in my directory have "-rw-r--r--" (including the fond file).

Any suggestions? I need to add that on another server this code worked.

Comment: I have additional information. I tried to run the code from the command line and I got "Could not find/open font". So, my assumption was in the correct direction. But I still do not understand why. Because "group" and "others" are allowed to read this file. What's a problem?

Comment: I solved the problem. Before the file name of the font I needed to put "./". I.e.: $font = "./LucidaBlaBlaBla.ttf". It worked. I do not know why but it worked.

Comment: You should write your final solution as an "Answer" and then accept it so this question doesn't appear in "No answers"

Answer (score 0):

/ means the root directory
./ means the current directory
../ means the parent directory

Hope this explains to you why it worked ;)